# How to add UIview over a ViewController and its NavigationController

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview, uinavigationcontroller

I have a `ViewController` with a `NavigationController` and I want to add a translucent `UIView` with some Buttons over the `ViewController` when I press a ViewController button, the problem is that I can not put the `UIView` over the `NavigationBar`. How can I solve  this?

This is my code ( Very simple)

```
-(void)setOpacityView
{
    opacityVw = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    opacityVw.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.8];


    WPCustomButton *closeBtn = [[WPCustomButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(230, 10, 80, 20)];
    [closeBtn setTitle:@"Close X" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [closeBtn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [closeBtn setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [closeBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(closeView) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [opacityVw addSubview:closeBtn];
}

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#pragma mark - Button methods

-(void) closeView
{
    [opacityVw removeFromSuperview];
}


-(void)setProfileImage
{
    [self setOpacityView];

    [self.view addSubview:opacityVw];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19257999/add-child-view-controller-to-uinavigationcontroller/19260092#19260092)

Try something like this:

```
-(void)setProfileImage
{
    [self setOpacityView];
    [self.navigationController.view addSubview:opacityVw];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add it to the AppDelegate's `UIWindow` instead.

```
- (void)setProfileImage
{
    [self setOpacityView];

    [ [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate].window addSubview:opacityVw];
}
```

Don't forget to change your view size:

```
opacityVw = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]window].bounds];
```

Comment: it does not work. I think it is because this viewController is not the next after appDelegate

Answer (score 0):

Just make it simple :

```
-(void)setProfileImage
{
    [self setOpacityView];
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
    [self.view insertSubview:opacityVw aboveSubview:self.view];
}

-(void) closeView
{
    [opacityVw removeFromSuperview];
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
}
```

Comment: I've edited my posts since I ve read your questions too quickly it should work as requested

Comment: Except he said nothing about hiding the navigationBar. He wants his translucent view over the nav bar as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can create MainViewController and put that as your window.rootViewController. Add your navigationController to this MainViewController. After that it you add the view to your mainViewController, it would be on top of navigation Controller.